# Javascript Add a button with value to html table?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, html-table

From two arrays I have created an HTML table. I'm trying to add a button to each row with value.

[Jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/thorstorm1102/yumq6v43/9/)

```js
var country = ["Norway", "Sweden", "Denmark"];
    var capital = ["Oslo", "Stockholm" , "Copenhagen"]

    var bodyString = '';
    $.each(country, function(index, ctry) {
        bodyString += ('<tr><td>'+ctry+'</td><td>'+capital[index]+'</td></tr>');
    });
    $('.countriesTable tbody').html(bodyString);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

  <table class="countriesTable">
      <thead>
          <tr><th>Country</th><th>Capital</th>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
      
      </tbody>
  </table>
</body>
</html>
```

With this array `var button_value = ["1","2","3"]`. I'm trying to add a button to each row with value from array. How to proceed from here?

Comment: you can proceed as you did with `country` and `capital` arrays or you want to do something else ?

Comment: I would use your current `$.each()` but then add the button element at that time. Where do you want it to appear?

Comment: button i'm able to create, but i couldn't assign value to that button

Comment: @Twisty Next to `country`,`captail`. Seperate column with three buttons

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Similar to how you have added the `country` and `capital` values in table, you can also add a `button` element.

```js
var country = ["Norway", "Sweden", "Denmark"];
var capital = ["Oslo", "Stockholm" , "Copenhagen"]
var button_value = ["1","2","3"]

    var bodyString = '';
    $.each(country, function(index, ctry) {
        bodyString += `<tr><td> ${ctry}</td><td> ${capital[index]}</td><td><button value="${button_value[index]}">${button_value[index]}</button> </tr>`;
    });
    $('.countriesTable tbody').html(bodyString);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

  <table class="countriesTable">
      <thead>
          <tr><th>Country</th><th>Capital</th>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
      
      </tbody>
  </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks. How to add `value=" "` to button from array instead of button name

Comment: In case you are planning to make a lot of string concatenation, I would suggest using `template strings`. I have updated my answer using a `template string` for appending table-rows

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following.

```js
var country = ["Norway", "Sweden", "Denmark"];
var capital = ["Oslo", "Stockholm", "Copenhagen"];
var buttons = [{
  value: 59,
  label: "FiveNine"
}, {
  value: 65,
  label: "SixFive"
}, {
  value: 123,
  label: "OneTwoThree"
}];

$.each(country, function(i, c) {
  var row = $("<tr>").appendTo('.countriesTable tbody');
  $("<td>").html(country[i]).appendTo(row);
  $("<td>").html(capital[i]).appendTo(row);
  $("<td>").html($("<button>", {
    value: buttons[i].value
  }).html(buttons[i].label)).appendTo(row);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="countriesTable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Country</th>
      <th>Capital</th>
      <th>&nbsp;</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

Your table will have to account for additional cells. You can also use `i` by itself if that is a better identifier.

Comment: If I have to use random values `var button_value = ["59","65","123"]`

Comment: @Zanthoxylumpiperitum you didn't include an example Array, so it was not clear from your post. You can just use the same index against the new array as was done in the other arrays. I would suggest an array of Object that include Value and Label or just the Values if the Label will be the same.